# Do Belkin Wemo switches integrate with Apple HomeKit?

Tags: wemo, apple-homekit

In March of 2016, [Belkin announced](http://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?articleNum=187953) that they would not be supporting Apple HomeKit any time in the near future.  This meant that integration was basically impossible across Apple devices.

However, that article was over a year ago now.  Has the status changed at all?  Is Belkin planning on integrating HomeKit any time soon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>I'm including the answer with a link to the official article, since I had a hard time finding it.  Hopefully, it will help someone.</sup>

#### The status has indeed changed.

Belkin published [this article](http://www.belkin.com/us/pressreleases/8804624237628/) on May 25 in which they explain that integration to Apple HomeKit is indeed in the foreseeable future: Fall 2017 is supposed to see the introduction of the Wemo Bridge, which Bridges between your Wemo switches and your Apple HomeKit.  Here's a quote from the article referenced:

> Continuing to expand its award-winning Internet of Things ecosystem, Wemo®, the smart home brand from Belkin International, today announced it plans to enable Apple® HomeKit™ compatibility to more than two million Wemo solutions on the market. With the HomeKit enabled Wemo Bridge, Wemo users will be able to ask Siri® on their iPhone, iPad or Apple Watch - “Siri, turn on Wemo” or “Siri, dim the living room lights,” or use the Apple Home app on any of these devices. Users will also be able to include Wemo products into scenes and rooms to work with more than one hundred other HomeKit compatible products and access them while on the go.

So the answer is, **yes, you should be able to link your Wemo Switches and Apple HomeKit soon.**

---

### Edit:

And... [it's live!](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F7C074/)